# How to find the rows which has diff column value from reference row column in same excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel which contains given few files present on each server.
My job is to find out which server has file size different compared to reference server.

So, in following example: file1 and file2 is present on all 3 servers but if we consider server1 as reference then file1 is diff on server3 and file2 is different on server2 so I have added column is diff Y/N.
Ho can we do it in excel using formula or some other technique for large set of data?

**Note:** Consider server1 has golden copy of data, so it should be used as reference while comparing same file on another servers.

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| Server  | File Name | File Size | Is Diff |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| Server1 | file1     | 2048      | N       |
| Server1 | file2     | 1256      | N       |
| Server2 | file1     | 2048      | N       |
| Server2 | file2     | 1325      | Y       |
| Server3 | file1     | 1092      | Y       |
| Server3 | file2     | 1256      | N       |
| Server4 | file1     | 1092      | Y       |
| Server4 | file2     | 1256      | N       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: What should happen if you have three different sizes? Is one server considered the reference for all others?

Comment: Yes. Consider server1 as golden copy server.

Comment: Your formula will fail if suppose 2 servers are having same file size but it differs from reference. Can you please recheck. I have updated the data in original question which has server4 rows too

Comment: @Koret Try this : `=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,B:B,$B$2,C:C,$C$2)+COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,B:B,$B$3,C:C,$C$3)=0,"Y","N")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood correctly, then this should work for you as I have commented above, using <kbd>COUNTIFS( )</kbd> function. `Server 1` has been taken as reference once for `File1` and `File2` as mentioned by OP.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(
    COUNTIFS(
        B:B, B2,
        C:C, C2,
        B:B, $B$2,
        C:C, $C$2
    ) +
        COUNTIFS(
            B:B, B2,
            C:C, C2,
            B:B, $B$3,
            C:C, $C$3
        ) = 0,
    "Y",
    "N"
)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

### Flag Rows Different Than First (Top-Most) Matching Rows

[image]

```
=LET(Data,A2:C9,sCol,1,sCrit,"Server1",dlCol1,2,dlCol2,3,
        y,"Y",n,"N",dlm,"@",
    sd,CHOOSECOLS(Data,sCol),
    dl,CHOOSECOLS(Data,dlCol1)&dlm&CHOOSECOLS(Data,dlCol2),
    sl,FILTER(dl,sd=sCrit),
    dr,IF(ISERROR(XMATCH(dl,sl)),y,n),
dr)
```